# passing variable from html to javascript is empty

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table that's populated via php/mysql.  I'm attempting to create a "unique" value for each row of the table, then pass that into a JavaScript function.

```
<td><a href="#" dataP="<?= $partNumber[x] ?>" onclick="popup(this)"><?= substr($avgCost[0],0,6) ?></a></td>


<script>
function popup(windowname) {
  var partNumber = windowname.getAttribute("dataP");  
  console.log(partNumber);
}
</script>
```

For some reason though, I'm not passing anything over to the function. `$partNumber[x]` is "ABCD" - so I would assume "ABCD" would be passed into the function, but my console just shows a blank space - not even a `null` or something...

Comment: Can you show the actual HTML that's sent to the browser?

Comment: What's the value of  `dataP` if you check the html?

Comment: I wouldn't make up my own attributes, especially when custom data attributes exist (`data-`)

Comment: basic debugging: have you done a "view source" to make sure there's actually something being output by PHP into that attribute?  `$partNumber[x]` should also be `$partNumber['x']`, otherwise you risk having a PHP warning output into your html at that spot as well.

Comment: @PaulRoub where do I find that?

Comment: @MarcB yes - there is an actual output to `$partNumber[x]`, and the syntax on that is correct for my application.  (Its value is `ABCD`).

Comment: Is the function `popup()` actually being called?

Comment: @TZHX - yes, it is being called.  I'm not sure how I look at the source, as the page is inside a div on another page.  If I click `view page source` I get the main page....

Comment: Sorry - simple overview by me... the code should have said `$partNumber[$x]`.  Sorry for wasting your guys' time! :(